# how to download apk files from android market to pc?

Tags: android, windows, apk, mobile-phones

Is it possible to download the android .apk  application from the android market to our pc?

Answer (score 12):

Probably this will help you.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html

Once you get access to android market from emulator you can probably get .apk from ddms

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the method told by the howtogeek.com. But it structs when i  try to sign into google account via new system image from emulator.It say's No Service error.[Click the to see screenshot of the error] http://bit.ly/fJKLV2

Answer (score 6):

Yes , You'll need the latest version of Chrome with SSL error notifications disabled, then you supply your device ID, email address and password (all stored locally on your computer to grab the Android Market cookie).

To anyone still need it , you can get it here : http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

Answer (score 3):

You can download all your installed apps. from mobile to SD Card. You just need to install an android application [appInstaller](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.IQBS.android.appInstaller&feature=order_history)...You just need to backup all your applications. This software generates apk files and stores in the SD card..And then you can store it in your pc..

Comment: Thank you karthik.I will try it and say

Answer (score 3):

you can install the android-sdk and use the adb command to pull the apk from your device.
The command is: adb pull

Answer (score 2):

This is an update to the post by Mur Votema.
The Android 2.2 with Market is available here
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/search/label/Market%20on%20Emulator

Answer (score 2):

Now you can do this by using this extension for Google Chrome: [APK Downloader](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in control of the network that you are using for the download, you could relatively easily grab it from the TCP stream:

```
Internet --- your_router --- wifi_AP --- your_Android_device
```

In the above diagram, the Android device connects to your WiFi access point, which is connected to your router, which connects to the Internet (and therefore the Android market). By running some capture tool (e.g. WireShark or tcpdump, even a capturing reverse proxy like Fiddler) on the router, you will see all the traffic passing across it, and you could capture it.

Possible caveats:

- you'll need to decrypt encrypted connections, if any (e.g. for HTTPS, dummy certificates can be substituted)
- more importantly, check if the license conditions for Market and the app allow this; depending what you intend to do with the files afterwards, this could be seen as a step in reverse engineering
- the device itself must be able to connect to Market (not sure about emulators etc.)

Comment: @Piskor: Sorry i can't understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Kris Rajkumar: I'm trying to say that it is possible. You need an Android device and control over a router between the device and Android Market; you download apps on the Android and capture TCP/IP traffic on the router; the APKs will be in this traffic. Clear enough?