# find the manifest from the apk

Tags: android, manifest

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459248/how-to-download-apk-files-from-android-market-to-pc) thread and I find it very useful but my question is how can I find the manifest ?

I see files like a,b,c,d.... and so on, and only one named com, inside this com I have more files but I could not find the manifest

I am viewing with this jd-gui tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to extract resources from APK and decode them from binary form.

Assuming that you followed installation instructions and using Windows - type in command line `apktool d <YOUR_APK_NAME_HERE>` - then it will unpack all resources from the application, including the manifest.