# Upload APK file

Tags: android

I get this problem when uploading a new version of my android application :

The APK must be signed with the same certificates as those of the previous version.

I have already make updates using the same private key withoutany problem; but when i update my Android SDK i get this problem.

Please any body know a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the updated APK is actually signed with the same certificate as the current version in the market place. To do that I would suggest executing the following command on both APKs:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs /path/to/apk
```

If they are the same then perhaps it is a bug with the Android Marketplace console?

Comment: How can i get the current version APK, i dont have it, how can i dowloand it without phone

Comment: It isn't straight forward but I believe it is possible. Take a look at this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459248/how-to-download-apk-files-from-android-market-to-pc

Answer (score 3):

Maybe updating your SDK has changed the certificates of your application, you have to change it in your app.

> **Publishing Updates on Android Market**
>
> At any time after publishing an application on Android Market, you can
>   upload and publish an update to the same application package. When you
>   publish an update to an application, users who have already installed
>   the application may receive a notification that an update is available
>   for the application. They can then choose to update the application to
>   the latest version.
>
> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have
>   incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes
>   in the  element of the manifest file. Also, the package name
>   must be the same as the existing version and the .apk file must be
>   signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing
>   certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will
>   consider it a new application, publish it as such, and will not offer
>   it to existing users as an update.
>
> If you plan to publish your application on Android Market, you must
>   make sure that it meets the requirements listed below, which are
>   enforced by the Market server when you upload the application.

Source : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketupgrade

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that updating the SDK has somehow changed the signing of the application. The signature is based purely on the developers private key.

Answer (score 1):

The fact of updating your sdk shouldn't have any effect to your apk uploading. 
Check and be sure that you signed your application with the same private key that you generated the first time you uploaded your application in the market, and you incremented versionCode and versionName in your manifest file.